# How to get full day hour date format in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I want to print a list of today date starting with 0th hour till 24 hour

```
const date = new Date().toISOString();
console.log(date) //21-06-01T17:09:40.766Z
```

the above code gives me current ISO dateTimestamp

I want dateTimestamp staring from 21-06-01T00:00:00Z,........,21-06-01T24:00:00Z
How to get that any simple way is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it using only JavaScript:

```js
var currentTimeStamp = new Date().getTime() // get current timestamp
var firstTime = (currentTimeStamp - (currentTimeStamp % 86400000)) // get the first hour of the day  

var totalMilliSecsInHour = 3600000 // milliseconds in one hour 

for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    console.log(new Date(firstTime))
    firstTime += totalMilliSecsInHour // after getting the date increment the timestamp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with luxon.
First get the first hour of the day, then only sum one hour until 24.

```js
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
const allHours = []; // Array of hours
const fistHour = DateTime.utc().startOf('day'); // this is the 00:00
const totalHours = 24;
let currentHour = 0;
    for (currentHour = 0; currentHour < totalHours; currentHour++) {
      const startHourDT = fistHour.plus({ hours: currentHour });
      allHours.push(startHourDT.toJSDate());
    }
console.log(allHours);
```

Dont forget instal `Luxon` fist with `npm i luxon --save`.

Hope it help you

PS. I don speak english very well.

Comment: Thanks!
[
  2021-05-31T18:30:00.000Z, 2021-05-31T19:30:00.000Z,
  2021-05-31T20:30:00.000Z, 2021-05-31T21:30:00.000Z,
  2021-05-31T22:30:00.000Z, 2021-05-31T23:30:00.000Z,
  2021-06-01T00:30:00.000Z, 2021-06-01T01:30:00.000Z,
  2021-06-01T02:30:00.000Z, 2021-06-01T03:30:00.000Z,
  2021-06-01T04:30:00.000Z, 2021-06-01T05:30:00.000Z,
  2021-06-01T06:30:00.000Z, 2021-06-01T07:30:00.000Z,
  2021-06-01T08:30:00.000Z ]

Comment: how to exclude 31st

Comment: Use `DateTime.utc()` instead of `DateTime.local()` to get in utc time, and avoid diffetent days, please mark the awnser if it help you, thanks

Comment: sure thank dood! can i pass a custom date?

Comment: Of course, example `const  fistHour = DateTime.fromObject({day: 22, month: 5}).startOf('day')`;